# The metric identification of a pseudometric on $C(\mathbb{I})$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a pseudometric $\mu$ on $C(\mathbb{I})$ defined by
$$\mu(f, g) = |f(x_0) - g(x_0)|.$$
I then take the metric identification of $(M, \mu)$ and am asked what familiar space this metric identification is isometric to?

This question has me pretty much stumped. In my head I am thinking it might be related to the discrete metric, but since I am not sure this could be 100% off-base. Any hints on how to start/what to look at?

Comment: Well, how many distinct points will there be in the metric identification?

Comment: Hmm. Is it 2? I may be going about this all wrong.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the metric identification?

Comment: Yes @DanielMcLaury , I am using the following definition for metric identification: if $M*$ is the set of equivalence classes in $M$ under the equivalence relation ~ and if $\rho*$ is defined on $M*$ by $\rho*([x][y]) = \rho(x, y)$, then $\rho*$ is a well-defined metric on $M*$. The metric space $(M*, \rho)$ is called the metric identification of $(M, \rho)$

Comment: Well, the important part is what $\sim$ is... do you know that?

Comment: Yes ~ is $x$ ~ $y$ iff $\rho(x, y) = 0$

Comment: Okay, so let's say $x_0 = 0$ for convenience.  Which functions are equivalent to $\sin(x)$, say?

Answer (score 1):

Extended HINT: For any $f,g\in C(\Bbb I)$, $\mu(f,g)=0$ if and only if $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$. Thus, if $\sim$ is the corresponding equivalence relation, $f\sim g$ if and only if $f(x_0)=g(x_0)$. Let $[f]$ be the $\sim$-equivalence class of $f$: by definition

$$\begin{align*}
[f]&=\{g\in C(\Bbb I):f\sim h\}\\
&=\{g\in C(\Bbb I):f(x_0)=g(x_0)\}\\
&=\{g\in C(\Bbb I):\mu(f,g)=0\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

For each $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ let $f_\alpha:\Bbb I\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\alpha$ be the constant function on $\Bbb I$ with value $\alpha$.

1. Show that for each $f\in C(\Bbb I)$ there is a unique $\alpha\in\Bbb R$ such that $f\in[f_\alpha]$ and hence such that $[f]=[f_\alpha]$.
2. If $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb R$, what is $\rho^*\left([f_\alpha],[f_\beta]\right)$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?